# How to get url and row id from database before scraping to use it in pipeline to store data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I'm trying to make a spider that gets some outdated urls from database, parses it and updates data in database. I need to get urls to **scrape** and ids to use it pipeline that saves the scraped data.

I made this code, but I don't know why scrapy changes the order of scraped links, looks like its random, so my code assing ids wrong. How can I assing id for every link?

```py
   def start_requests(self):
        urls = self.get_urls_from_database()
        # urls looks like [('link1', 1), ('link2', 2), ('link3', 3)]
        for url in urls:
            # url ('link1', 1)
            self.links_ids.append(url[1])
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url[0], callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True)

    def get_urls_from_database(self):
        self.create_connection()
        self.dbcursor.execute("""SELECT link, id FROM urls_table""")
        urls = self.dbcursor.fetchall()
        return urls

    def parse(self, response):
        item = ScrapyItem()
        link_id = self.links_ids[0]
        self.links_ids.remove(link_id)

        ...

        item['name'] = name
        item['price'] = price
        item['price_currency'] = price_currency
        item['link_id'] = link_id

        yield item
```

Because the links are not processed in order output is assinged to wrong item in database:
Name of item 1 is saved as name of item 3, price of item 8 is price of item 1 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## async

Scrapy appears to be scheduling GETs asynchronously.

Your code does not deal gracefully with that.

## naming

What you get from the DB is not `urls`,
but rather `rows` or `pairs`.

Rather than writing:

```
        for url in urls:
```

and using `[0]` or `[1]` subscripts,
it would be more pythonic to unpack the two items:

```
        for url, id in pairs:
```

## url → id

You attempt to recover an ID in this way:

```
        link_id = self.links_ids[0]
```

Consider storing DB results in a `dict`
rather than a `list`:

```
        for url, id in pairs:
            self.url_to_id[url] = id
```

Then later you can just look up the required ID
with `link_id = self.url_to_id[url]`.

## iterating

Ok, let's see what was happening in this loop:

```
    for url in urls:
        self.links_ids.append(url[1])
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url[0], callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True)
```

Within that loop you wind up running this line:

```
        self.links_ids.remove(link_id)
```

It appears you're trying to use
a `list`, that has either zero or one elements,
as a scalar variable,
at least in a setting where Scrapy behaves synchronously.
That is an odd usage; using e.g. the `dict` I suggested
would probably make you happier.

Furthermore, your code assumes callbacks will happen
in the sequence they were enqueued;
this is not the case.
A `dict` would sort out that difficulty for you.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you :)